# File transfer using sockets (C#) - received file doesn't contain full data

Tags: c#, sockets, arrays

I created a server and a client for a file transfer using socket connection.
The problem I'm facing is that the received file, if its size is over 8KB, is incomplete.

If you faced this issue, can you guide me onto finding out what I'm doing wrong (on the server  /client side)?

Here are both methods:

**Client:**

```
#region FILE TRANSFER USING C#.NET SOCKET - CLIENT

class FTClient
{
    public static string curMsg_client = "Idle";
    public static void SendFile(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            //IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("localhost");
            //IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress[0], 5656);

            string IpAddressString = "192.168.1.102";
            IPEndPoint ipEnd_client = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IpAddressString), 5656);
            Socket clientSock_client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);


            string filePath = "";

            fileName = fileName.Replace("\\", "/");
            while (fileName.IndexOf("/") > -1)
            {
                filePath += fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
                fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
            }


            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
            if (fileNameByte.Length > 5000 * 1024)
            {
                curMsg_client = "File size is more than 5Mb, please try with small file.";
                return;
            }

            curMsg_client = "Buffering ...";
            string fullPath = filePath + fileName;

            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);

            curMsg_client = "Connection to server ...";
            clientSock_client.Connect(ipEnd_client);

            curMsg_client = "File sending...";
            clientSock_client.Send(clientData, 0, clientData.Length, 0);

            curMsg_client = "Disconnecting...";
            clientSock_client.Close();
            curMsg_client = "File [" + fullPath + "] transferred.";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message == "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")
                curMsg_client = "File Sending fail. Because server not running.";
            else
                curMsg_client = "File Sending fail." + ex.Message;
        }

    }
}

#endregion
```

and **Server:**

```
#region FILE TRANSFER USING C#.NET SOCKET - SERVER

class FTServer
{
    IPEndPoint ipEnd_server;
    Socket sock_server;
    public FTServer()
    {
        //make IP end point to accept any IP address with port 5656
        //these values will be altered depending on ******* (and/or other ImportSystem)
        //this was initially coded, but threw a SocketException on sock.Bind(ipEnd) {Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network addres/port) is normally permitted}
        //ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
        //
        //I'll set it like this (giving the IP through a string)
        string IpAddressString = "192.168.1.102";
        ipEnd_server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IpAddressString), 5656);
        //
        //creating new socket object with protocol type and transfer data type
        sock_server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        //bind end point with newly created socket
        sock_server.Bind(ipEnd_server);
    }
    public static string receivedPath = @"C:\Users\Adrian.Constantin\Desktop\Simulare_Forder_Import\";
    public static string curMsg_server = "Stopped!";


    public void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            curMsg_server = "Starting...";

            sock_server.Listen(100);

            curMsg_server = "Running and waiting to receive file.";

            Socket clientSock = sock_server.Accept();

            byte[] clientData = new byte[512000];

            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData, SocketFlags.None);
            clientSock.ReceiveBufferSize = 8192;

            curMsg_server = "Receiving data...";

            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
            string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + "/" + fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)); ;
            bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);

            curMsg_server = "Saving file...";
            bWrite.Close();

            clientSock.Close();
            curMsg_server = "Received and Archived file [" + fileName + "]; Server stopped.";

        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            curMsg_server = "File Receving error.";
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} Error cide: {1}", ex.Message, ex.ErrorCode));
        }
    }


}

#endregion
```

edit: 24.08.2012 (I've managed to find out the issue and to get the server to work)
Full code for server is :
**SERVER:**

```
#region FILE TRANSFER USING C#.NET SOCKET - SERVER

class FTServer
{
    IPEndPoint ipEnd_server;
    Socket sock_server;
    public FTServer()
    {
        string IpAddressString = "192.168.1.102";
        ipEnd_server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IpAddressString), 5656);
        sock_server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        sock_server.Bind(ipEnd_server);
    }
    public static string receivedPath = @"C:\";
    public static string curMsg_server = "Stopped!";


    public void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
            curMsg_server = "Starting...";

            sock_server.Listen(100);

            curMsg_server = "Running and waiting to receive file.";

            Socket clientSock = sock_server.Accept();
            clientSock.ReceiveBufferSize = 16384;

            byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 50000];

            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData, clientData.Length, 0);
            curMsg_server = "Receiving data...";

            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
            string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);

            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + fileName, FileMode.Append));
            bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);


            while (receivedBytesLen > 0)
            {
                receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData, clientData.Length, 0);
                if (receivedBytesLen == 0)
                {
                    bWrite.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    bWrite.Write(clientData, 0, receivedBytesLen);
                                        }
            }


            curMsg_server = "Saving file...";
            bWrite.Close();

            clientSock.Close();
            curMsg_server = "Received and Archived file [" + fileName + "] (" + (receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen) + " bytes received); Server stopped.";

        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            curMsg_server = "File Receving error.";
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} Error code: {1}", ex.Message, ex.ErrorCode));
        }
    }

}

#endregion
```

Answer (score 8):

You have fallen into the most classic pitfall of socket usage. This one is as old as the idea of sockets developed at Berkely..

You see, you have not read the docs :)

See the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145160.aspx for example - what is the return value?

Both Send and Receive methods are not obligated to actually send/receive all the data you have provided. That's why they both return an 'int' describing how many was send/received actually. This design is held because the system's internal buffers are limited. If you provide an array of 999GB to be sent, how your network card will store that before it actually sends that?

You see the behaviour for 8KB threshold, probably because this is the size of the intenal buffer, or maybe the max size of a TCP network packet.. I don't remember how big they were, but it is something around that.

To send and receive your data poperly, you have to use some kind of loop, for example, in the simplies form:

```
int bytesToBeSent = arr.Length;
int bytesActuallySent = 0;
while(bytesActuallySent < bytesToBeSent)
    bytesActuallySent += socket.Send(arr, bytesActuallySent, bytesToSend - bytesActuallySent, ....);
```

and recv - similarly.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26f591ax.aspx):

> the Receive method will read as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter

It **does not*** guarantee to read everything in one go; it reads what it can *up to* the maximum (the size of the buffer in your case). When reading from **any** stream, you usually need to have a Read/Receive loop. In your case, I would say that buffer is vastly oversized, and that you should read the length bytes manually, then just have a Read/Receive loop over a **small** buffer (say, 4096 bytes) for the file handling. You don't need a 512k buffer.

A classic Read/Receive loop would be:

```
int read;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while((read = socket.Receive(buffer)) > 0) {
    output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Comment: and the same with Send.. I'd guess that the actual problem is there, but of course both send and recv must be handled properly.

Comment: heh, quite true, especially with UDP and mixed packet order :)

Answer (score 0):

You need delay before each sending methods about 200 ms, because your receive buffer is overwritten by incoming data. 
example:

```
Thread.Sleep(200);
socket.send(sendbuffer);
```